# Calderon's commutator and differential operator[Edited]

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

First,
$$C_1f(x)=p.v.\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{A(x)-A(y)}{(x-y)^2}f(y)dy$$
Here, $C_1$ is the Calderon's first commutator.
The author says, the $L^p$ boundedness of $C_1$ is coincides with $[|D|,A]$ where
$$[|D|,A]f=|D|(Af)-A(|D|f)$$, and $\widehat{|D|f}=2\pi|\xi|\hat{f}(\xi)$.
The following is what I have tried.

First I assumed that
$$|D|Af-A|D|f=(|D|A)f$$
holds. So
$$\begin{split}\widehat{(|D|A)f}(\xi)&=(|D|A*f)(\xi)\\&=\int_\mathbb{R}|\eta|\hat{A}(\eta)\hat{f}(\xi-\eta)d\eta.\end{split}$$

How can I improve this to have it coincides with $C_1$?

- A is a function such that $A'\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$
- From Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis - Schlag, Muscalu

Comment: what is $A$? On what space are your operators defined? What do you mean by «the boundedness of $C_1$»? I cannot tell what exactly is it you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited my question.